# Cleveref, capitalize and plurals

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, capitalization, ntheorem

I [recently thought my problem was solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330666/capitalization-with-cleveref), but it is more involved. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\crefname{conjecture}{conjecture}{conjectures}
\crefname{solution}{solution}{solutions}

\begin{document}

\begin{conjecture} \label{c1} Something happened.
\end{conjecture}

\begin{conjecture} \label{c2} Something else also happened.
\end{conjecture}

\begin{solution} \label{s} A lot of things happened.
\end{solution}

\Cref{c1,c2,s} are both \namecref{s} and \namecref{c1}.

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

> Conjectures 1 and 2 and solution 1 are both solution and conjecture.

I would want the output to be:

> Conjectures 1 and 2 and Solution 1 are both solution and conjecture.

How do I achieve this? In other words, I want *everything* to be capitalized in a `\Cref` statement with multiple references. In fact, I would even be happy if I could achieve this with a `\cref` statement, because I want *everything* to be capitalized when it has a number, but as illustrated in the example, I do not want `\namecref` output to be capitalized.

---

#### Thoughts

The solution to my previous question was the `capitalise` option, but this does not work here because it relies on cleveref auto-defining the names from the ntheorem definitions, and if we do this the plural for `conjecture` is not defined. The cleveref manual states:

> Therefore, if the plural form is ever required, cleveref will produce
>   a "\reference type undefined" warning, and type-set the cross-reference where the
>   plural form is required as:
>
> **??** \ref{label} ...
>
> In this case, you will have to provide an explicit \crefname or \Crefname definition yourself, to define the plural form as well as the singular form.

If I do that, the `capitalise` will not work any more because:

> [...] if you explicitly define a \cref variant to not be capitalised, cleveref
>   will still honour your definition. In other words, you're responsible for defining the capitalisation correctly in your own format definitions.

Maybe what I want is not possible, but it seems odd to me that the `capitalise` option is so useless.

Comment: It's not at all clear why “solution” should be uppercase, unless you want it to be *everywhere* uppercase.

Comment: @egreg: As stated in the question, I indeed *do* want every reference capitalized, but I also want a command like `\namecref` that outputs a lowercase word. I.e. this is **T**heorem 9, a reference to a **t**heorem. This is also the reason why I would be happy with the `capitalise` option, but it does not work well (actually, at all?) with plurals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\lcnamecref`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\Crefname{conjecture}{Conjecture}{Conjectures}
\Crefname{solution}{Solution}{Solutions}

\begin{document}

\begin{conjecture} \label{c1} Something happened.
\end{conjecture}

\begin{conjecture} \label{c2} Something else also happened.
\end{conjecture}

\begin{solution} \label{s} A lot of things happened.
\end{solution}

\cref{c1,c2,s} are both \lcnamecref{s} and \lcnamecref{c1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will accept because it fixes the example, but again it does not solve my problem because I can not get `lcnamecref` to work. Time for another question ;).